# Javascript setInterval is not running

Tags: javascript, setinterval

the following code returns nothing. Is there something I am missing here? Shouldn't this say 'hi' twice...
Thanks in advance

```
var done = 1;
var id;
id = setInterval(function() {
        if(done > 3) {
            console.log('hi');
            done++;
        } else {
            clearInterval(id);
        }
    }, 500);
```

Comment: `done > 3` should be `done < 3`

Comment: Reverse this condition : `if(done > 3) {`

Comment: yes my mistake should be < 3 but still does not work

Comment: @kyle as you can see in my snippet it does work by only changing `>` into `<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if statement in the interval, directly terminated the interval because `1 > 3 == false`

```js
var done = 1;
var id;
id = setInterval(function() {
    if(done < 3) {
        console.log('hi');
        done++;
    } else {
        clearInterval(id);
    }
}, 500);
```